# Insert multiple background images of HTML body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to insert 3 different images as the background of my html page. I know how to insert one image as the background of my page, but I want to split the background into three grids.

Basically, I want to have two columns of 6 units (col-sm-6) for the background. On the first 6 units, I want to have a background image. On the right side of the 6 units, I want to further divide that into two equal sizes to fit in 2 different background images. This is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

How can I go about do this? I'd like the images to cover the whole length and width of my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the simple demo.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 div1">
      " your content goes here"  
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 div2">
                " your content goes here" 
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 div3">
                " your content goes here" 
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div1 { min-height:500px; background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1449960238630-7e720e630019?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=975&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1925); background-size:cover; background-position:center;}
.div2 { min-height:250px; background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1453227588063-bb302b62f50b?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=975&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1925); background-size:cover; background-position:center;}
.div3 { min-height:250px; background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1433878455169-4698e60005b1?crop=entropy&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=975&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&w=1925); background-size:cover; background-position:center;}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to approach what you're trying to achieve. The first thing that came to mind was to have two divs, one for the background grid and one for everything in the foreground.

The background grid would have `position: fixed` and use Bootstrap to layout the grid as you described.

The foreground could have `position: absolute; top: 0%;`. Then place all of your page content inside of the foreground div.

Check out codepen for an example of how you could set this up.
http://codepen.io/smrubin/pen/yOzWrR

Might not be the best approach, but this should at least get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This works perfectly fine. But I've accepted the other answer only because of its simplicity.

Comment: No problem. It's worth noting that with the other solution, your foreground is constrained to the same layout as your background (it must be in the two column, one with a split row grid). My solution allows you to flow your foreground content however you want. It is also worth noting that with the other solution, your two columns will no longer be same height, if the content exceeds the min-height properties. You can see this illustrated in this codepen, which simply added more content to the div. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKboQv